# Spring 4 @Scheduled stops working

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I am using @Scheduled annotation to run a cron job. The scheduling works for some time, and then stops working.
I will give simplified snippets of my code:

This is the scheduler:

```
//org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
@Scheduled("*/30 * * * * *")    
public void performTask() {
    logger.info("Starting agent");
    getAgentAsyncTask().execute();
    logger.info("Ending agent");
}
```

This is the task which is executed by scheduler

```
//org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async
@Async(TASK_EXECUTOR)
@Override
public void execute() {
    logger.info("Starting task");
    //send some rest requests
    logger.info("Ending task");
}
```

Both: "Starting agent" and "Ending agent" are logged equal number of times. So, each scheduling is ending properly.

Both: "Starting task" and "Ending task" are logged equal number of times. So, definitely, "task" is not blocking things.

But it just stops logging after some time. What might be the issue?

Here, TASK_EXECUTOR is the following bean:

```
 @Bean(TASK_EXECUTOR)
 public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor createDefaultTaskExecutor() {
          ThreadPoolTaskExecutor te = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
          te.setMaxPoolSize(15);
          te.setCorePoolSize(15);
          te.initialize();
          return te;
    }
```

Spring version:

> 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Are you running this inside or outside of a container?  Also, what version of Java?

Comment: Inside the container (Annotation based config, I have @EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync). Java version 8

Comment: have you read? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17909404/206466

Comment: As stated in the top answer of @xenoterracide's link, what does a kill -3(or use JVisualVM) gives you ? => to see if any threads are stuck somewhere

Comment: Hi, Actually, the task that the task executor was supposed to run had an infinite loop, that's why it stopped being scheduled. Thank you for all your responses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such a situation might be caused by an infinite loop in the body of the scheduled method or if there is a call to an external system and the control waits synchronously to receive the response without any timeout.

Try it by yourself with this simple code snippet. The method will be started only once and will not be started after the specified interval of 5 seconds.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void printPeriodically() {
    System.out.println("This is my periodic method");
    while(true) {};
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this `fixedRate` stops after a few days. I have similar usage to @coolscitist - start and stop logs and call `@Async` function. Strange...

Comment: Is there no way to set a timeout on the scheduled task executor?

Comment: @dukethrash I guess there is always a possibility to check for a timeout inside the body of the method, isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

see whether job is getting hanged or not. incase if it does.. the task will not execute after some time i mean after reaching max pool size. check you implementation code whether threads are released after successful execution.