# Spring boot @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot release 4 and I use cron jobs I have some jobs like:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=5000,fixedDelay=5)
public void SendSmsPluto()  {

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.SendSmsPluto is started");

    sbean.testSend();

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.SendSmsPluto is ended");
}


@Scheduled(initialDelay=10000,fixedDelay=10000)
public void getSmsPlutoStc(){

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is started");

    sbean.PlutoQuery(new Long(4));

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is ended");
}

@Scheduled(initialDelay=13000,fixedDelay=10000)
public void getSmsPlutoZ(){

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is started");

    sbean.PlutoQuery(new Long(5));

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is ended");
}

@Scheduled(initialDelay=15000,fixedDelay=10000)
public void getSmsPlutoZI(){

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is started");

    sbean.PlutoQuery(new Long(6));

    logger.info(" ** CronJobs.getSmsPlutoStc is ended");
}
```

These cron jobs worked well but after a long time, maybe 2 or 3 days, they stopped. When I look at the log file, I find for example one of them start and not ended so the remainder stopped.

Comment: Maybe there was a connection time out error, and that's why cron job stopped, make sure you are setting connection timeout error before connecting somewhere.

Comment: fixedDelay is accurate the next job will start after the first finished so it's mean i wait about 5 ms after fininshed

Comment: @ParvizMakari where i can set time out connection

Comment: it depends on where you're connecting, I mean database, httpconnection...based on the source, set timeout connection

Comment: @ParvizMakari yes i have connection pool and set time out connection and in another method i have httpconnection but i not setting time out for it

Comment: refer this answer, here someone suggested how to set timeout connection
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909404/spring-scheduler-stops-unexpectedly